# Unpacking msgpack from respond in python

Tags: python, response, msgpack

I get the following error while trying `msgpack.unpack`:

```
ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.
```

Part of my code:

```
r1=requests.get('http://localhost:3000/fs?path='+r.json()['object'])
unp = msgpack.unpackb(r1.content)
```

Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 2):

The doc's aren't very clear about this, but `msgpack.unpackb` is a "one-shot" unpacker - you can't give it a larger stream with extra data in it. I assume that you are getting multiple msgpack objects and you can read them with `msgpack.Unpacker` as in

```
r1=requests.get('http://localhost:3000/fs?path='+r.json()['object'])
for unp in msgpack.unpackb(r1.content):
    do something...
```

The reason for this is that the `msgpack` deserializer reads data in chunks for greater efficiency. For `unpackb`, where you can only return one object, its chunk reader consumed more of the data stream than it should have and you lost data.